# Posting to Bottle server. How do I get the request data?

Tags: jquery, python, bottle

I'm having trouble getting the request data on the server side. I'm a newbie when it comes to web code som bear with me. Here's my (simplified) code:

**html**

```
<form id="form" action="http://localhost:8080/report" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <div name="navigation-bar" id="navigation-bar">
        <input type="submit" value="Post" onclick="post()" />
    </div>
 </form>
```

**js**

```
function post() {
    $.post("http://localhost:8080/report",
            {"id": 1},
            function(data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            "json");
}
```

**py**

```
@route('/report', method='POST')
def report():
    payload = request.json
    return payload
```

payload is always None. What is the correct way to get the data when sending with jQuery?

Comment: the data in the alert window look fine? If so then you have to take a closer look into what's store in request. I'm not sure it would be request.json

Comment: It never reach the callback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the datatype to `"json"` only tells jquery how to interptet the *response*, it doesnt't change the format of the request, that is still sent `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

But `bottle`'s [json handling](http://bottlepy.org/docs/stable/api.html#bottle.BaseRequest.json) only works if the request is sent using the correct content type of `application/json`, so if you want to use that, you need to manually set the content type for the request and encode the request data to json:

```
function post() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/report",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({"id": 1}),
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

That however only works for submission using javascript, the normal form submission won't work, that means you should change your submit button to a normal button or make sure your oncklick returns false.

Comment: Thank you. That solved retrieving the data on the server. Now I need to figure out why my callback isn't triggered, but that's beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Found out why the callback wasn't triggered and it had nothing to do with any of the content in my question or your answer.

Comment: Can you tell me how you did that in python using Bottle?

Comment: @Guru There isn't much to it, if you send a request with the correct json content type then within the route handling it `bottle.request.json` will contain the parsed json object.

Comment: @mata you mean this (http://pastebin.com/raw/izRneX51) should print the json string, But it is not printing anything

Comment: @mata here's the same concern I am dealing with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39867323/write-post-web-service-in-python-bottle

Comment: @Guru - since in that example you import `request` directly, it should be `request.json`, not `bottle.request.json`. Works fine for me using `wget --header="Content-Type: application/json" --post-data='{"foo": "bar"}' http://localhost:8080/response -S -qO-` to post the request. But this isn't the palce to discuss separate questions.

Comment: @mata yup that works but what to do in case when Content-Type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded I tried using "request.forms" is not working. And Yaa i know it's not a place, but at the place noone is on the same pitch to get my concern. Pls help